# Untyped Arguments in C header files

Tags: c, kernel

I'm trying to add a system call to a `FreeBSD 9.3.0` system.And I found this line in the header file `/usr/src/sys/sys/systm.h`:

```
int vsscanf(const char *, char const *, __va_list) __nonnull(1) __nonnull(2);
```

My question is about the `__va_list` argument.I have seen similar questions on untyped arguments, but they stated that they are assumed as `int` by the compiler and also not used anymore.But I know that `__va_list` is not an `integer` and is not used as such.So what type does it have?

Comment: Maybe it's a macro...

Comment: @Corluk I think it probably is.I'll look into it and report.

Comment: [Follow the source](http://sources.freebsd.org/RELENG_9/src/sys/ia64/include/_types.h) and it expands to one of either: `__builtin_va_list` (a gcc built-in type) or `char *` (which doesn't work for varargs). Look up `va_list` for details on what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what type does it have?

`__va_list` does not have a type, it **is** the type. That function declaration is lacking variable names also for other parameters.

If you do

```
int a, b, c;
sscanf("1 2 3", "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Typically `sscanf` creates `va_list` object, and calls `vsscanf`. `vsscanf` then uses the `va_list` object to keep track of where "optional" arguments are, when items are retrieved.

All variable argument functions work like this.